# Problem with counting MD5 from bitmap stream C#

Tags: c#, image, md5, memorystream

When im passing Bmp as stream, function always return,

```
D4-1D-8C-D9-8F-00-B2-04-E9-80-09-98-EC-F8-42-7E
```

but file saving on disk correctly.
When I load bpm from disk, function return correct MD5. Also passing "new Bitmap(int x, int y);" with different value return same MD5.

Why its happening?

```
    public static string GetMD5Hash()
    {

        Bitmap Bmp = new Bitmap(23, 46); // 
        using (Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage(Bmp))
        using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(32, 44, 2)))
        {
            gfx.FillRectangle(brush, 0, 0, 23, 46);
        }



        using (var md5 = MD5.Create())
        {
            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                Bmp.Save(memoryStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
 \//EDITED:     Bmp.Save(@"C:\Test\pizdanadysku.bmp"); // Here saving file on disk, im getting diffrent solid color

                return BitConverter.ToString(md5.ComputeHash(memoryStream)); //Always return D4-1D-8C-D9-8F-00-B2-04-E9-80-09-98-EC-F8-42-7E - I noticed that is MD5 of empty 1x1px Bmp file
            } 
        }
    }
```

Can somebody explain this strange behaviour?

Comment: You have two completely different images in this code... you have `image` and you have `Bmp`.

Comment: Yes, should be `Bmp` insted of `image`, but problem was with position of the stream. @Michael Randall anwser resolved problem.

Comment: interesting choice of a file name

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Stream operations tend to only move forward for various reasons (including the fact some streams can only be read, E.g `NetworkStream`), so saving the image is likely just progressing the stream to the end.

Additionally, and pointed out by various helpful editors ([@jpa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/914716/jpa)).

```
D4-1D-8C-D9-8F-00-B2-04-E9-80-09-98-EC-F8-42-7E
```

Is the classic MD5 sum of an empty string.

My gut feeling is you just need to reset the position of the stream to get your desired result

```
memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)
// or 
memoryStream.Position = 0;
```

Comment: Could you please explain why not resetting the position of the stream would produce OP's error?

Comment: @jpa thanks for the edit, I'm was surprised this got so much attention. I have updated and attributed